# Show that if $\mu$ is semifinite, and $\mu(E)=\infty,$ then for all $C>0$ there exists $F\subseteq E$ with $C<\mu(F)<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

So I'm trying to prove that claim from Folland's Real Analysis. The techniques I was using on the other problems weren't working, so I thought I would try something else. I was wondering if someone could verify my proof, or tell me what I did wrong. Thank you.

To motivate what's going on, I am planning to use Zorn's Lemma.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Suppose the claim doesn't hold. Choose a $C>0$ such that exists no exists no $F\subseteq E$ with $C<\mu(F)<\infty.$ 
Let $$S=\{F\subseteq E:0<\mu(F)<\infty\}$$ be indexed by inclusion. Since semifinite we see $S\not=\emptyset.$ Let $\{F_i\}_{i\in I\subseteq\mathbb{N}}$ a chain. If $I$ if finite, then by finite additivity $\bigcup_{i\in I}F_i\in S$ is an upper bound for our chain, so WLOG $I=\mathbb{N}.$ By continuity from below it follows that
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}F_i \right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(F_i)\leq C.$$
Then $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}F_i\in S$ is an upper bound for our chain. So, every chain has an upper bound in $S$. By Zorn's Lemma choose $F\in S$ maximal with respect to inclusion.

Note that 
$$\mu(E)=\mu(F)+\mu(E\backslash F),$$
so $\mu(E\backslash F)=\infty.$ Since $\mu$ is semifinite we can and do choose $F'\subseteq E\backslash F$ with $0<\mu(F')<\infty.$ Since $F,F'$ are disjoint it follows that 
$$\mu(F\cup F')=\mu(F)+\mu(F')<\infty,$$
hence $F\cup F'\in S.$ Since $F$ is maximal it follows that $F'=\emptyset$ and $\mu(\emptyset)>0.$ A contradiction, hence there exists $F\subseteq E$ with $C<\mu(F)<\infty$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not right. To apply Zorn's lemma you have to show *every* chain has an upper bound, not just every countable chain.

(Simple counterexample to the version of Zorn's lemma you're applying here: Let $A$ be an uncountable set and let $X$ be the class of countable subsets of $A$, ordered by inclusion. Then every countable chain in $X$ has an upper bound, but $X$ does not have a maximal element.)

One could fix this with a little fiddling. Happily, the sort of constructions that you need to fix your argument actually give a direct proof, without any Zorn's lemma:

Let $$\alpha=\sup\{\mu(F):F\subset E, \mu(F)<\infty\}.$$We need to show that $\alpha=\infty$. Suppose that $\alpha<\infty$. There exists  a sequence of sets  $F_n\subset E$ with $\mu(F_n)<\infty$ and $$\mu(F_n)\to\alpha.$$ Let $$S_n=F_1\cup\dots\cup F_n.$$Since $F_n\subset S_n$ and $\mu(S_n)<\infty$ the  definition of $\alpha$ shows that $$\mu(F_n)\le\mu(S_n)\le\alpha.$$Hence $$\mu(S_n)\to\alpha;$$since $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ this shows that if $$S=\bigcup S_n$$then $$\mu(S)=\alpha.$$Now (as above) choose $F\subset E\setminus S$ with $$0<\mu(F)<\infty;$$then if $S'=S\cup  F$ we have $$\alpha<\mu(S')<\infty,$$contradiction.